# Cannot Create ActiveX Component when I try to use Text to Speech in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, sapi

I want to convert text to speech in my LAN chatting program in VB.Net 2010 Express

I am using Windows XP and I want to use this code to convert the received message to speech when my program is in Idle, All Done and there's no error but when I tried to convert the text to speech this error was shown to me:

> Cannot Create ActiveX Component

My Code is:

```
Dim SAPI
SAPI = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")
SAPI.Speak(Message)
```

How can I resolve that, I searched google for a while but didn't find anything!

Comment: Have you installed [Speech API SDK for Windows XP](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10121)?

Comment: No, Is this important?, That is my First Time to use Windows XP, I am using Windows 7 & Up always and I don't install that! Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's important.  Windows XP doesn't ship with SAPI 5.1 by default, and Windows Vista and above does.